# how to set before filter to index action in active admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I want to display something before a particular page loading.(Like a flash message after checking some condition). I am using active admin. How can i do this?

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  config.batch_actions = false
  config.paginate = false
  menu false

  actions :index, :destroy, :show

  index do
    column 'ID', :id
    column :name
    column :short_name
    column :start_date
    column :end_date
    column :aggregatable
    column :branch do |user|
      link_to user.branch.name, active_user_branch_path(id: user.branch_id)
    end
    column :lock_status
    default_actions( name: 'Actions' )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question regarding how to set before filter in ActiveAdmin:
before filter should be set in controller.

Pattern:

```
  controller do
    before_filter :my_filter, only: %i(index)

    private

    def my_filter
      #logic here
    end

  end
```